# Sidekiq pro web UI must be READONLY for specific users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, sidekiq

Is it possible to prevent sidekiq deletion and creation of jobs/queue for specific users? We are using sidekiq with ruby on rails.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not sure how to do this within the gem, you should be able to create a fork of the gem and add checks in the view files - (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/web/views/retries.erb)

However, you could also write a pull request in for this as I think it might be good functionality as well! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but we do not want to over ride views. is there anything else you have.

Answer (score 1):

Web UI authorization is available in Sidekiq Enterprise.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Web-UI